# react native third party method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: react-native

Info:

```
"react-native": "0.42.3"
"react-native-ble-manager": "3.1.2",
"react-native-camera": "0.12.0",
"react-native-datepicker": "1.4.5",
"react-native-default-preference": "^1.3.1",
```

Suddenly my android project does not work, the error is `method does not override or implement a method from a supertype` in all third party libraries.

But yesterday everything works fine, I have not changed anything. Is there anyone can tell me how to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find it in github, someone made mistake, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19272